# Get and set position of element programmatically in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

Is it possible to get and set position/bounds programmatically of element on window? Let's say, we have simple `Text` and want to move it `50dp` on `y` axis.

```
Text(text = "Hello", modifier = Modifier.padding(8.dp).fillMaxWidth())
```

Comment: [Modifier.offset](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/ui/layout/package-summary.html#(androidx.ui.core.Modifier).offset(androidx.ui.unit.Dp,%20androidx.ui.unit.Dp))

Comment: offset is anchor for drawing. It does not change collision box

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I interpret your question correctly, then you would like to move a Text 50dp on
the y-axis and the Text and the 50dp space above the text should be clickable.

This is one solution to create a small custom composable:

```
@Composable
fun TextWithPos(content: String, modifier: Modifier, x: Int, y: Int, clickFun: () -> Unit = {}) {

    Text(text = content, modifier = modifier
            .defaultMinSizeConstraints(minHeight = y.dp)
            .clickable(onClick = clickFun)
            .padding(top = y.dp))

}
```

This Composable sets up a Text with a `minHeigth` of some dp (`minWidth` not used
here), then sets the `clickable`, then a `padding` with some dp. Actually, compose
does no distinguish between margin and padding anymore, it's just some *space*.

Compose processes Modifiers in order, thus `clickable` covers the space (padding)
and the text inside `Text`. If you move `clickable` below the `padding` then
the clickable area only covers the text inside `Text`.

Here a Preview with a clickable action to show the clickable area. Because the
function sets a modifier and hands it over to the custom composable these
modifiers take precedence over the Modifier set in the custom composable.

```
@Preview(showBackground = true)
@Composable
fun TextPosPreview() {
    PlaygroundTheme {
        Column() {
            TextWithPos(content = "Hello", modifier = Modifier
                    .padding(start = 16.dp, end=16.dp), x = 0, y = 50) {
                counter++
            }

            var counter by remember { mutableStateOf(1) }
            Text(text = counter.toString(), modifier = Modifier
                    .padding(16.dp))

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/ui/layout/package-summary#offset

```
Text(text = "Hello", modifier = Modifier.padding(8.dp).offset(y = 50.dp))
```

Comment: Add "clickable". You will see, clickable area does not change. Offset just changes drawing anchor

Comment: @AdrianGrygutis Wrap the Text to Box, apply offset to the Box but clickable to the Text

Comment: Good idea... but would be hard to implement for lists with draggable elements